# Jean Grey's last act in "Dark Phoenix" and "Days of Future Past"

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-dark-phoenix

In *X-Men: Days of Future Past* we see that at the end when Logan 'wakes up' he meets Jean Grey (surprised she's alive, but she is nevertheless). This is fine as presumably they've altered the timeline now and the events of *X-Men: The Last Stand* are nullified.

However, we see in *X-Men: The Dark Phoenix* that Jean Grey (although younger) encounters her 'Dark Phoenix' mode and goes full elemental, turning into some sort of pure energy.

**How do we reconcile the two Jeans?** Or do we not?

Comment: Now it doens't matter ;D

Comment: [Timelines, man.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129222/is-the-outcome-of-x-men-apocalypse-already-known-thanks-to-the-ending-of-x-men) It's all fair game.

Comment: As of now, there doesn't seem to much chance of any resolution, since the Disney/Fox merger. Due to the way that many of the films have had pretty negative reception, more than likely, Disney will just do a complete reboot and ignore the Fox movies.